# How to build a files structured view using react and SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, treeview

I'm building a files structured view using react with SVG where every element connected with dashed dots.

I can't align everything properly, maybe i can find an appropriate answer here :)

My current approach is to recursively iterate through my data object and passing positions via props.

Each nested object has following props:

```
const dataObj = {
name: "Web Dev",
markdown: "01",
children: [] //children have the same data object properties
}
```

!! `children` have the same data object properties